# server problem in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am hitting an url when the server shutdown.Then the program hang up.May i know how to handle the error when the server shutdown.I mean at that situation I want to give an alert.

Thanks in advance

this is in objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate you supply to an NSURLConnection should handle the error.  It will receive the `-connection:didFailWithError:` message in the event that anything goes wrong.  [Listing 4 here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) gives a simple example of just logging the error.  If you want an alert dialog to appear you can just sent `-presentError:` with the [NSError](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as a parameter to a view or a `NSDocumentController`.

Answer (score 1):

Check reachability api code example in cocoa documentation.